# C# client how to invoke wsdl file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, wsdl

My customer gave me a .wsdl file to access their webservices. Using VS2008 I can create a project, but I don't know how to use the .wsdl file in it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't invoke WSDL file, you add service reference from the file.

To add reference, right click on the project, select `Add Service Reference`. Paste path to your wsdl file and hit `Go`.

[image]

If you want to use legacy Web Service client, select `Add Web Reference` and paste path to the wsdl file from there.

I recommend to use WCF (Add Service Reference option).

To use the service reference add code like this:

```
var serviceClient = new ServiceReferenceName.MyClassClient();
serviceClient.DoSomething();
```

You also need to update config file with the server URL that you customer should provide you with:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://UrlFromYourCustomerHere"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="xxx"
            contract="MyServiceReference.xxx"
            name="xxx/>
</client>
```

Comment: +1 for recommending a different method, but still answering the original question.

Comment: @Alex - Is it possible to change the WSDL URL  dynamically or at runn time in c# ?. Could you please share some link

Answer (score 1):

> A Web reference enables a project to
>   consume one or more XML Web services.
>   Use the Add Web Reference Dialog Box
>   to search for Web services locally, on
>   a local area network, or on the
>   Internet.
>
> After adding a Web reference to your
>   current project, you can call any
>   methods exposed by the Web service.

To add a Web Reference

1. On the Project menu, click Add Web Reference.
2. In the URL box of the Add Web Reference dialog box, type the URL to obtain the service description of the Excel Web Services, such as http:////_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx or http:///_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx. Then click Go to retrieve information about the Web service.
     Note Note:

   You can also open the Add Web Reference dialog box in the Solution Explorer pane by right-clicking References and selecting Add Web Reference.
3. In the Web reference name box, rename the Web reference to ExcelWebService.
4. Click Add Reference to add a Web reference for the target Web service.
5. Visual Studio downloads the service description and generates a proxy class to interface between your application and Excel Web Services.

Read

[How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It is not recommended to use legacy Web References. WCF (Service Reference) is newer and better way to create SOAP clients.

Comment: Also, OP mentions that there is no reference to asmx, there is just wsdl file available.