# Importing WSDL file gives Error

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have a list of `.wsdl` files provided by the client. I have tried to import them as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119163/892788).

But when I do that, it gives an error. This error is shown as below.

```
    The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'file:///[path]/WebServices_8_0_2_0/WebServices/wsdl/common.xsd'.
  - Could not find file '[path]\WebServices_8_0_2_0\WebServices\wsdl\common.xsd'.
  - Could not find file '[path]\WebServices_8_0_2_0\WebServices\wsdl\common.xsd'.
  - Could not find file '[path]\WebServices_8_0_2_0\WebServices\wsdl\common.xsd'.
   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have no idea of what this `common.xsd` file is . Can some one atleast tell me the reason of this happening and a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `common.xsd` file probably contains type definitions used in the WSDL. Try to download the file manually (the URL should be in the WSDL) and save the file next to the WSDL file.

Comment: After setting getting the commom.xsd file, it worked. Thanks.